# С прописной или со строчной пишутся КНИГИ Пятикнижия? Склоняются ли названия первых трёх - Бытия, Исхода, Левита?

Tags: прописная-строчная, склонение-имён-собственных

> – Теперь хотелось бы поговорить об авторстве. Кому приписывается **Книга
>   Исход**, кто считается ее автором?
>
> – **Книга Исход** была написана пророком Моисеем. Я уже упомянул, что эта
>   группа книг – Бытие, Исход, Левит, Числа, Второзаконие (первые пять
>   книг Ветхого Завета, вы можете прочитать их названия, если откроете
>   оглавление Библии) – называется Пятикнижие. Или еще добавляется слово
>   – Пятикнижие Моисеево, что означает, что Моисей их и написал.

**[источник](https://tv-soyuz.ru/peredachi/besedy-s-batyushkoy-efir-ot-29-sentyabrya-2016g)**

---

[Содержание книг Пятикнижия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5):

> - Бе-решит (Книга Бытие) — первая книга Торы, Ветхого Завета и всей Библии.
> - Шемот (Книга Исход) — история Исхода народа Израиля из Египта под руководством Моисея.
> - Ва-йикра (Книга Левит) — посвящена, в основном, священническому законодательству и храмовой службе.
> - Бе-мидбар (Книга Чисел) — посвящена сорокалетнему странствованию евреев по пустыне до вступления в Землю Израиля.
> - Дварим (Второзаконие) — заключительная книга Пятикнижия. Основная её часть — это наставления и пророчества сынам Израиля на все последующие
>     поколения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Склоняются, если нет зависимого слова, но не склоняются, если оно есть.

*В **Бытии** сказано, что Каин убил Авеля*, но *В книге **Бытие** сказано, что Каин убил Авеля*.

Ну и писать название библейских книг лучше с заглавной буквы. Во-первых, потому что это имя собственное, а во-вторых, потому что в религиозных текстах принято писать заглавную в любой спорной ситуации. Правила в отношении заглавных букв в религиозных текстах не устаканены, Лопатин и Розенталь тут друг другу противоречат, а при таком раскладе, по-моему, лучше оставлять авторское решение.